# best way to change output of a field?

Tags: php, drupal-7

Im using drupal 7

I have a date field.

Which displays the date selected as it is supposed to.

However I would to change the display to say 'this date is almost over' under certain php validation or 'this date is now closed' under different validation.

I cant use string over reides as it doesnt accept php. Would I have to use a custom module and use hook form alter or node api?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you would have to use a module to adjust how the image field is displayed. You can either create a new display format using hook_field_formatter_info() along with hook_field_formatter_view(), or you can hook an existing display using hook_field_formatter_view() by checking $display['type']. I would recommend the former.

Here is an example of how the two hooks could work together:

```
function modulename_field_formatter_info()
{
    return array(
        'modulename_formatter' => array(
        'label' => t('Custom Date Format'),
        'field types' => array('date'),
        ),
    );
}

function modulename_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display)
{
    if ($display['type'] != 'modulename_formatter')
        return;

    foreach ($items as $delta => item)
    {
        if ($item['date'] < time()) //Or 'datetime' or 'datestamp'
            $element[$delta]['#markup'] = 'this date is now closed.';
    }
    return $element;
}
```

I might have some of the indices wrong, but they should be pretty close.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_info/7
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_view/7